# IIS 8.5 MVC Core 2.0 Website hosting View update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8.5

I never see this kind of problem in IIS before.
I have core 2.0 Application hosting in IIS 8.5 in Windows 2012R2.

Core 2.0 Website is working fine, Except change in any view folder files (HTML Contnet), DLL or CSS Foder, It's not updating.

I did following steps without any success:

1. Restart website as well IIS and Finally server also.
2. Remove website and recreate it also Change folder.

It takes first setting in start up and then If anything change happen in Views, dll or CSS. It's not reflecting the website.

Comment: You don't need to add `<br/>` tags on Stack Overflow. Markdown is supported. See the help center for [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thnx for your comment.